# "Relativity in terms of rank"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is meant by the underlined part

> There is no equivalence between the ranks of the defence forces and the police forces since there is no government established **relativity in terms of rank.** ([source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Security_Force))

Answer (score 2):

The phrase 'relativity in terms of rank' could also be read as 'correspondence in terms of rank' or 'equivalence in terms of rank'.

There is no correspondence between, for example, a Commandant in one organization and a Major in another organization.  Neither outranks the other, because there is no relative ranking between the two organizations - even though they might use the same words for their ranks.

To use an absurd example, there is no relativity in rank between the Chief of Surgery in a hospital and the Assistant Chef in a restaurant.  Their organizations have nothing to do with each other.